# Active Choice Reactive Parameters with Parameterized Scheduler

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, scheduler, parameterized

I have some parameterized build in Jenkins with several Active Choice Reactive Parameters: par1, par2.
par1 is defined by combo, and par2 value depends on par1:

```
switch (par1) {
    case 'value1': return 'test1'
    case 'value2': return 'test2'
    default: return 'test'
}
```

It works fine for manual trigger, but fails if I try to use parameterized shedule trigger:

```
H * * * * %par1=value1
```

Is it possible to solve this issue somehow?

Comment: The poverty is that if a user selects one value from the multi-select combo box, then Jenkins will give you a value that you'll select. If you do select multiple values from the combo box (actually the plugin don't say any reference to "COMBO", i think you meant Multi Select of Check Boxes) then Jenkins will return the values as a STRING but comma separated. PS: It'll not be in the format of `['a','b','c',..]` but it'll come as `a,b,c,d,..`. Now, in your Groovy code, you are not handling how to parse that string where it contains a `,` comma in it. Setting it to `H * * * * *` is INVALID value

Comment: Use: `* * * * *` if you want it to run every minute. Or `H/2 * * * *` if you want the job to run every 2 minutes or acc. See how `cron` works/it's help. Jenkins will also show if the response to any such value and tell you if it's valid or when Jenkins will schedule it next.

Answer (score -1):

Your input for periodic is supposed to run per hour (1).

Change this `H * * * * %par1=value1` to either `* * * * *` every minute OR `H/1 * * * *` (1 hour) or `H/2 * * * *` (every 2 minutes). yea, it's kind of confusing when you use 1 it makes it one hour vs 1 minute (with `H/1`)

Also, make sure your par2 (Groovy code section within Active choice reactive parameter) is handling cases where `par1` is not just a single value (`test1`) i.e. it can be `test1,test2,test3,...` when a user would  have selected multiple values for par2 parameter (if it is a `Multiple Select` type).

Comment: This does not address the question. The question isn't about picking the right schedule expression; but rather about the fact that active choice completely disregards the parameter value provided in `%par1=value1`

Comment: @RaGe you are right possibly. It seems like a wait period within the Active Choice Plugin (Uno plugin) itself could help let the "triggered" / scheduled run work as it may be possible that the user runs parameterized scheduled run then the plugin is going super fast and not even waiting to get the value of dependent variable par2 (which depends upon par1). One can test this by creating own plugin (forking it, making changes by adding a wait) and see if that new .jpi/.hpi works for scheduled par1/par2